# Problems when using nested foreach on checkboxes loaded dynamically

Tags: php, foreach, nested-loops

I need to use nested foreach for dependent checkboxes.

```
    <input type="checkbox"  name="all[]" value="<?php echo $row_bus_details['busid'];?>" >

     <?php
      $book_side_result = mysqli_query($db,"select * from advt_sides");
                                           while($book_side_row=mysqli_fetch_array($book_side_result))
    {
                                           ?>
   <input type="checkbox" name="bookingside[]" value="<?php echo $book_side_row['advt_side_id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $book_side_row['advt_side']; ?><?php echo $row_bus_details['busid'];?>" > <?php echo $book_side_row['advt_side']; ?><br/>
                                          <?php } ?>
```

I need to loop the selected values of second checkbox if the first checkbox is selected.

I wrote the code like

```
$i = 0;
           $busid = isset($_POST['all']) ? $_POST['all'] : array();
           foreach ((array)$busid as $item) {


       if(!empty($_POST['bookingside'])) {
            foreach($_POST['bookingside'] as $side) {
                $sql_book_side=mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO `advt_book_side`(bus_id,sides_id) VALUES ('$item','$side')");
                $i++;
            }
        }
     }
```

The result I need is just like the image below

[image: required output]

Answer (score 0):

You need to save data in serialize array from in data base like:
       $sql_book_side=mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO    `advt_book_side`(bus_id,sides_id)  VALUES ('$item',serialize(array('left'=>1,'right'=>1,'back'=>0)))");

Print check box with check uncheck using below code

```
     $book_side_result = mysqli_query($db,"select * from advt_sides");
     while($book_side_row=mysqli_fetch_array($book_side_result))
        {
        $array = unserialize($book_side_row['sides_id']); 
        foreach($array[0] as $side){        
    ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="bookingside[]" value="<?php echo ($side)? $side:0; ?>">

    <?php } 

  }     ?>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work properly,  If I select 'left' from first one and 'back' from second one, total 4 entries will insert into the db like 2 entries for each one

Comment: you need to save row data according to "bus_id" and in second column "sides_id" here you can store ids in serialize associative array e.g array('left'=>2,'right'=>1)

Comment: I think there a problem in the nested foreach section, because in the second loop it will all the sides_id

Comment: Did you created new row for every checkbox ?

Comment: fow the left most checkbox